# 2016 CCC S4 Combining riceball code?? C++

Tags: c++

the quesiton is like this :
Alphonse has N rice balls of various sizes in a row. He wants to form the largest rice ball possible for his friend to eat. Alphonse can perform the following operations:

If two adjacent rice balls have the same size, Alphonse can combine them to make a new rice ball. The new rice ball's size is the sum of the two old rice balls' sizes. It occupies the position in the row previously occupied by the two old rice balls.
If two rice balls have the same size, and there is exactly one rice ball between them, Alphonse can combine all three rice balls to make a new rice ball. (The middle rice ball does not need to have the same size as the other two.) The new rice ball's size is the sum of the three old rice balls' sizes. It occupies the position in the row previously occupied by the three old rice balls.
Alphonse can perform each operation as many times as he wants.

Determine the size of the largest rice ball in the row after performing 0 or more operations.

Input Specification
The first line will contain the integer, N (1≤N≤400).

The next line will contain N space separated integers representing the sizes of the riceballs, in order from left to right. Each integer is at least 1 and at most 1000000.

For 1 of the 15 available marks, N=4.
For an additional 2 of the 15 available marks, N≤10.
For an additional 2 of the 15 available marks, N≤50.
Output Specification
Output the size of the largest riceball Alphonse can form.

Sample Input 1
Copy
7
47 12 12 3 9 9 3
Output for Sample Input 1
Copy
48
Explanation for Sample Input 1
One possible set of moves to create a riceball of size 48 is to combine 12 and 12, forming a riceball of size 24. Then, combine 9 and 9 to form a riceball of size 18. Then, combine 3, 18 and 3 to form a riceball of size 24. Finally, combine the two riceballs of size 24 to form a riceball of size 48.

My code is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<int> rice;
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i< num; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        rice.emplace_back(temp);
    }
    int change = 0;
    int chain = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i > -1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 1; k < num-j; k++)
            {
                if(rice[j] == rice [j+k])
                {
                    chain++;
                }
                else
                {
                    k = num-j;
                }
            }
            if(chain != 0)
            {
                for(int m = 1; m <= chain; m++)
                {
                    rice[j] = rice[j] + rice[j+1];
                    rice.erase(rice.begin()+j+1, rice.begin()+j+2);
                    change = 1;
                    if(m == chain)
                    {
                        num -= chain;
                        change = 1;
                        chain = 0;
                        j=-1;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(j < num-2)
            {
                if (rice[j] == rice[j+2])
                {
                    rice[j] = rice[j] + rice[j+1] + rice[j+2];
                    rice.erase(rice.begin()+j+1, rice.begin()+j+3);
                    change = 1;
                    j=-1;
                    num-=2;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        if(change == 0)
            {break;}
        change = 0;
    }
    sort(rice.begin(),rice.end());
    cout << rice.back() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the test case that doesn't work right now is input: 10 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 and the output should be 14, but the only way to get that is to ignore the 1 at the beginning which i got no idea how to do / thks a lot

Comment: Please show the test cases that don't work, your output and the expected output

Comment: "*I can't find any problems through debugging.*": What have you done for debugging? While stepping through the code with the problematic test case, at which point do the variables change in an unexpected/unintended way? Is the output correct when you run it with the debugger? If not, there should be a point where the program behaves in an unintended manner.

Comment: The simple case of `2 2 2` is going to fail to give the optimal answer as it does `4 2` instead of `6`. And if you switch the order of checking, `2 2 2 2` gives `6 2` instead of `8`... Or is your program crashing?

Comment: the test case is input:                                                        10
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2                                                                                                                                                                         and the output should be 14, but the only way to get that is to ignore the 1 at the beginning which i got no idea how to do